# div tag that opens downward on mouse click

Tags: html

I have a current webpage that is broken into two sections. The top section contains various controls for filtering content on the webpage, and the bottom section contains a grid of the content.

What I want is encapsulate the filter controls in a div tag that initially is completely hidden except for a button link that will say something like "Click to Expand". Upon clicking the button link the div will open up downward to expose the filter controls that are in it. **However, I don't want the div to just suddenly appear, because that's too easy and boring.** I want the opening of the div to be noticeable as it slides downward to expose the content.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about achieving it? I'm not a CSS monkey, but I've done a fair amount with jQuery.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ...

So, instead of clicking the div, you could just add the click function to a button somewhere else on the page.

---

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" 
  style="position: relative; left: 10px;" />

$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

```
$('#expandBtn').click(function() {
  $('#filterDiv').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to jQuery there is also the scriptaculous.js [blind down](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-blinddown) and [slide down](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-slidedown) effects.